# I am trying to take in a user input and match it with a string in Bash (macOS)

Tags: bash

I am trying to take in a user input and match it with a string in Bash (macOS)

```
#!/bin/bash

s2=“something”

echo please input your whatever you want, ya know

read string

if [ "$string” == "$s2" ]
then
  echo match
fi
```

Comment: I suggest to replace all `”` by `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
s2="something"
echo please input your whatever you want, ya know
read string
if [ $string == "$s2" ]
  then echo "match"
fi
```

Comment: Other Bourne shells likely choke on `==`. You should use `=`, which is the POSIXly correct string comparison operator. Also, $string should be quoted to avoid surprises when it is empty or unset.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you must use ASCII double quotes in shell scripts, not the fancy curly double quotes. Next, the *correct* (portable) string comparison operator for shells is `=`, even though bash, in a misguided attempt to ease programmer life with less error messages, also accepts `==`.

A more flexible way though, is using `case`:

```
case $string in
  ($s2) echo "match";;
  (foo) echo "got foo";;
  (*)   echo "no match";;
esac
```